# Powering Arduino and L293D with the same Power Supply

Tags: arduino-uno, power, battery, l293d

I am relatively new to Arduino and plan to power an Arduino and an L293D Motor Driver with the same 9V power supply as in the diagram below.

I tried to simulate this with Tinkercad, but it seems like Tinkercad always powers the Arduino with an extra USB Cable, so I can't test it with only 1 power supply.

Would the 9V battery power both the Arduino and the L293D in this example?

[image: Tinkercad Circuit]

Comment: Don't use one of the little rectangular 9V "transistor batteries". Those don't provide enough current to power a motor for very long at all (probably single-digit minutes) before they are discharged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem. You used the Vin for 9V, and shared grounds.

I suggest using a bypass capacitor (typically 0.1 uF) for the L293D VCC, but I don't have experience with using a L293D.

Also, you need to check if the battery can deliver enough current for both motors and the Arduino.